# How to disable the popup of Google translate in chrome while it still translates

Tags: google-chrome, translation

It is very annoying. When browsing a website that I know is not in English and I trust Googles translation the popup some times comes and destroys the layout and it's impossible to work with the website then. If only the pop is disabled (more like , yeah please no popups for the next hour or so, but I guess that would ba feature)

Answer (score 5):

In Google Chrome options, there is an option to disable this. Click on the wrench icon and then on the "Under the hood" tab and look for "Suggest to automatically translate sites..."

Comment: that stops translation altogether. I want translation but not the popup

Comment: I don't think that's an option you can change then. You could try the Google Code forums for Chrome and ask there.

Answer (score 1):

If you disable Translation on Chrome settings **you can still translate** sites on different languages than yours by right clicking on any page and choosing "Translate to ......"

Answer (score -1):

After you choose to translate a page, click "Options" on the right side of the bar. Choose "Always translate X to Y," and I think that will kill the popup.

Comment: if it worked like this then there would not be any issue.

Answer (score -1):

I  just  had  to  go  into  Google settings 
Click on Advanced settings  at bottom of  page.
Click on Rest Browser Settings  and it  cleared  the
annoying pop up !!